# vis.js Dataset from MVC Controller ViewBag

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am pretty new to JSON and am trying to plug in some of my data to the [vis.js](http://visjs.org/) library. Right now I have a controller:

```
public ActionResult Vis()
        {
            var data = _context.Primers.Select(p => new { id = p.Id, label = p.Code }).ToList();
            JsonResult primers = new JsonResult() { Data = data };
            ViewBag.Primers = Json(primers);
            return View();
        }
```

The vis.js documentation has the following getting started code:

```
    // create an array with nodes
    var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
        {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
        {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
        {id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
        {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
        {id: 5, label: 'Node 5'}
    ]);
```

So I figured I just need to create my own `var nodes`, drop it in there and it should work. I am having trouble creating the object from my EF Linq query above though. I am using the following code to debug:

```
var primers = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Primers))');
var visPrimers = new vis.DataSet(primers);
console.log(visPrimers);
```

But I can see that the object visPrimers is `Length: 0` and the `data` attribute is empty. I have to go to `_options -> Data -> data` within the `visPrimers` object in order to find the array my Linq query returns.

I'm not sure I am doing this right. I know `vis.DataSet` can take Json data because their documentation says so, but I am not sure how exactly I need to format my data from my controller to make it the same format as the

```
[
        {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
        {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
        {id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
        {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
        {id: 5, label: 'Node 5'}
    ]
```

that the `vis.DataSet` function takes.

I hope this makes sense. Any and all help appreciated!

Comment: Your `ViewBag` property is already json. And you should not be using `ViewBag` anyway. Just use `var data = _context.Primers.Select(p => new { id = p.Id, label = p.Code }); return View(data);` and in the view `var primers = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` (although you should be projecting the data into a view model, not an anonymous object)

Comment: what would the property in the model look like, if you don't mind me asking? would it be virtual?

Comment: Create a view model (say) `public class Data` with properties `public int id { get; set; }` and `public string label { get; set; }` and the query would be `_context.Primers.Select(p => new Data { id = p.Id, label = p.Code });` and in the view `@model IEnumerable<Data>`

Comment: and how exactly do I make that into json in the view?

Comment: As per my first comment - `var primers = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` :)

Comment: Ok thanks. I will give that a shot

Comment: Why not organise the comment to become an answer? I'd upvote that :)